# Проверьте правильность (и неправильность)

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Если существует в мире «нищая страна с высокими
   ценами», имя ей: Папуа – Новая Гвинея!
2. Монумент в честь освобождения ( или, все-таки нужно так…) монумент, возведенный в честь освобождения.

Comment: Контекст "монумента"...Несколько ржавых пушек среди джунглей, заросшийподземный ход военного предназначения и монумент в честьосвобождения этой земли австралийскими войсками – вот и вседостопримечательности города.  После "имя ей", думаю, нужно тире? Но тире уже есть в названии страны.Кавычки остались от прежнего варианта. Если существует понятие «нищая страна с высокими ценами», то она находится именно здесь!

Comment: Не нужно тире. И "возведенный" не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

~1. Если это не прямая цитата и не парафраз с намеком, то кавычки не нужны. А если они, то нужна ссылка на источник, навскидку я такого выражения не помню.
Остальное нормально. Хотя улучшать стилистику можно до бесконечности, не вижу в том большой необходимости.

~2. Зависит от официального (или хотя бы общепринятого) названия оного монумента. Если название типа "Бабы коптят крокодила", то "возведенный" необходимо. А если название так и звучит "в честь освобождения", то зачем что-то менять? Вообще при упоминании названий мелких топонимов, тем более рукотворных, лучше придерживаться общепринятых версий, а не изобретать велосипед.
Насчет тире - по желанию. Тире такой знак, что его можно вставлять чуть ли не везде по самым разным мотивам. Например, чтобы подчеркнуть интонационный перепад, эффект неожиданности. Но судя по общему тону повествования, вам он здесь не нужен.

Comment: Поясню, где суть. Изначально было так. (Если существует понятие «нищая страна с высокими ценами», то она находится именно здесь!)
Подумал, что слово «здесь» уже неуместно: когда я был там, можно было так сказать, а, по возвращении – нет. Поэтому решил исправить, или заменить.

Comment: Нет, это не та суть, которая скажется на правописании. Существенным будет только то, у вас эта мысль про понятие первородная или усыновленная? Это про кавычки. Остальное не вижу надобности улучшать.

Comment: Ой, пардон, двоеточие же еще спорное, там тире, конечно, больше подходит по смыслу. Но это тоже с вашей "сутью" не связано.

Answer (score 0):

1. Двоеточие не нужно, а кавычки-то зачем? И лучше бы "если... то".
2. Контекст нужен. Если без контекста, то "монумент в честь освобождения" выглядит вполне достаточным.